# rollup-js with rollup-plugin-multi-entry - multiple file outputs/problem with duplicate constant names

Tags: rollupjs

I am fairly new to rollup and I have an issue with transpiling/compiling a library where there are multiple input files where many of the files contain duplicate constant names.

My `rollup.config.js`:

```
import multiEntry from "rollup-plugin-multi-entry"
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel"
export default {
    input: __dirname + "/src/*.js",
    plugins: [
        babel({}),
        multiEntry()
    ],
    output: {
        file: __dirname + "/lib/main.js",
        format: "esm",
    }
}
```

Many of the source files contain constants named `ENTITY_NAME`:

```
export const ENTITY_NAME = "entity1name"
export const ENTITY_NAME = "entity2name"
```

When I run rollup, I get the following warning:

```
rollup-plugin-multi-entry:entry-point re-exports 'ENTITY_NAME' from both packages\common\blah\src\entityOne.js and packages\common\blah\src\entityTwo (will be ignored)
```

... so the resulting `main.js` does not contain `ENTITY_NAME`.

How do I get around this? It would the only two possible solutions would be to output to:

1. Individual files,
2. A single file containing each input file compiled separately.

I have looked for how to configure either of these solutions, but I cannot find anything. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved. I needed to add the following to my rollup.config.js: -

```
preserveModules: true,
```